# Add Custom Made View in Interface Builder to Another View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a custom UIViewController in Interface Builder (in my storyboard) and I want to add this view I assembled into another view programmatically. I have made a class for the view controller I made but simply importing and adding that custom class as a subview doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to load an instance of the view controller from the UIStoryboard object and add it's view as a subview. That code would look something like this:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController* myVc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ident"];
[self.view addSubview:myVc.view];
```

Make sure you set the identifier field for your view controller in IB and pass that to the "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" method.

Comment: Ahh, didn't know about this trick. However I am getting a crash and console error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setFrame:]: unrecognised selector. Is this because view controllers don't have a setFrame property?

Comment: Not to worry. Rather than passing the view controller itself, I simply create the view controller as suggested and then return the view property.